# How to not skip to a new line but change the word while console logging?

Tags: node.js, npm

In node js when I use console.log it skips to a new line this time I want the existing string to be changed rather than logging something new, how do I have achieve that in node terminal?

Comment: You should upload your intended code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.stdout.write()` to write to stdout without the implicitly appended newline.